# Which (if either) of these two possibilities is the better choice?

Tags: grammaticality, numbers, time, adverbials

Could you please tell me which of the following sentences is right?

- Please arrange a meeting for today, 10 a.m. so that we can finalize the plan.
- Please arrange a meeting so that we can finalize the plan today, 10 a.m.

To my understanding, if a sentence has date or time, it should be placed at the end of the sentence.

Comment: "if a sentence has date or time, it should be placed at the end of the sentence" is a general rule for sentences describing the time when something happens, such as "He went home at 10" or "he plays golf on Tuesdays". It isn't a rule native speakers will always follow (emphasis allows variation in word order) and it doesn't relate to absolutely every sentence, so you can say "8am is a good time for a stroll", likewise "please arrange a meeting for 10am today to finalise the plan" seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

*10 AM* is being used to modify the time of the meeting, **not** the time of finalization of the plan. The first sentence makes it clear the day and time refer to the *meeting*, while the second might be (mis)construed as stating the the plans will be finalized exactly at that time.

That said, in conversation, *10 AM* might have been added as an afterthought, and most people would understand it refers to the time the meeting is to begin.